# How to find match from two Lists (from MySQL and csv)

Tags: python, mysql, list, csv

I am trying to match outcome of data from two Lists.

First data source is from MySQL.

Second data source is from csv.

The code for the first output (MySQL) or b is like:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "username", "pwd", "databasename")
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "select ID from Table1"
cursor.execute(query)
a = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
b = ('[{}]'.format(', '.join(a)))
```

The code for the second output (csv) or c is like:

```
db = pd.read_csv(File, usercols=['ID'], skiprows=skip)
c = dg['ID'].values.tolist()
```

Second data source is csv file.
I was trying bottom codes to get the match.

```
set(b).intersection(c)
set(b) & set(c)
```

But, I do not see the match as I expected.

For instance, first List has data like:

```
[111111, 2222, 3333333, 4444444]
```

Second List has data like:

```
[8888888, 2222, 6748987, 3688777, 55555]
```

I was expecting to get the result of:

```
set([2222])
```

But I only got

```
set([])
```

Is there any reason such as data type (that might be causing no match) from two Lists?

Comment: Running your code is giving me the expected outcome.

Comment: `>>> x = [111111, 2222, 3333333, 4444444]
>>> y = [8888888, 2222, 6748987, 3688777, 55555]
>>> set(x) & set(y)
{2222}`

Works fine for me.

Comment: Any reason it does not work from my end? Would it be due to Varchar (MySql)  vs. Number (csv) data type inside Lists?

Comment: btw, what crazy things are you doing here: `b = ('[{}]'.format(', '.join(a)))`? Shouldn't you then compare a to c and not b to c?

Comment: That part is just to delete single quote around a. The original output from MySql has all single quote around a (Varchar). So, I did one more process to delete a which is b.

Comment: Basically, your join() func accepts a list and joins it into a single string -> format() inserts it into another string, and finally set() tears it to single characters like this `>>> set(b)
{'5', ' ', ',', '3', '1', ']', '4', '2', '['}`.

If you need a list of integers instead of a list of strings, why not to convert them just in the above comprehension: `a = [int(item[0]) for item in cursor.fetchall()]`

Comment: I cannot convert string into integer because there are some value that are not numbers on MySQL. How can I convert number into string on the second case (csv)?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, intersection should work. I tested your code and got:

```
ls1 = [111111, 2222, 3333333, 4444444]
ls2 = [8888888, 2222, 6748987, 3688777, 55555]

set(ls1).intersection(ls2)
```

Output:

```
{2222}
```

Another way of doing this would be:

```
ls1 = [111111, 2222, 3333333, 4444444]
ls2 = [8888888, 2222, 6748987, 3688777, 55555]

[x for x in ls1 if x in ls2]
```

output:

```
[2222]
```