# Convert integer to string type when retrieving values from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am trying to convert output of data (from Integer to String) from a List generated using Pandas.

I got the output of data from a csv file.

Here is my code that covers expression using Pandas (excluding part where it shows how to come up with generation of object 'InFile' (csv file)).

```
import pandas as pd
....

with open(InFile) as fp:
     skip = next(it.ifilter(
        lambda x: x[1].startswith('ID'),
        enumerate(fp)
     ))[0]

dg = pd.read_csv(InFile, usercols=['ID'], skiprows=skip)
dgl = dg['ID'].values.tolist()
```

Currently, output is a List (example below).

```
 [111111, 2222, 3333333, 444444]
```

I am trying to match data from other List (which is populated into String or Varchar(data type in MySQL), but somehow, I cannot come up with any match. My previous post -> [How to find match from two Lists (from MySQL and csv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849828/how-to-find-match-from-two-lists-from-mysql-and-csv)

So, I am guessing that the data type from the List generated by Pandas is an **Integer**.

So, how do I convert the data type from Integer to String?

Which line should I add something like *str(10)*, for an example?

Comment: You want to convert `ID` to string?

Comment: ID is just the name of column.

Comment: Yes, I understood that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.astype`:

```
dgl = dg['ID'].astype(str).values.tolist()
print(dgl)
```

Output:

```
['111111', '2222', '3333333', '444444']
```